# Mercurial git extended diff format and revision numbers

Tags: mercurial

It seems that when using the git exteneded diff format, which is needed to properly support renames. mercurial doesn't add the revision ids in the command line it prints in the patch, for example:

> diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt

Instead of:

> diff -r 86b54773cb1d -r 354c20900a62 test.txt

Is there a way to make it do add a revision? It's quite useful when looking at patches later...

**EDIT:** git adds a line like the following to handle this:

> index e4ff69d..09eb727 100644

Why can't mercurial add a line like this too:

> index 86b54773cb1d..354c20900a62 100644

since it doesn't track file permissions like git it can always just invent something using the umask or some default, but that's still better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're out of luck.  That's called `--git` because it's supposed to mimic the diff format git creates and accepts, so it excludes any mercurial-isms.

You could probably use `hg export --git` to get a mercurial comment block at the top which will include the hashes.

Comment: From the question details it seams that "revision numbers" means "revision hashes", which are not local. So the question really is, can the hashes be included in the diff line?

Comment: Ah, you're right.  It's still not possible to alter the output, but at least now it's a sensible thing to wish for. :)   Updating my answer.

Comment: git does add a line like the following:
index e4ff69d..09eb727 100644

Why can't mercurial add something similar, possibly using it's 12 character hashs by default instead of the shorter git default?

Comment: This doesn't help you, but mercurial's `diff --git` reports the permissions of new files by adding a line like `new file mode 100644`. Your question sounds like the kind of thing mercurial's creators might want to add, in the future...

Comment: @alexis I think they copied that syntax from git.  The goal of --git was peace and interop, which why it doesn't emit its own hashes if I understand correctly.

Comment: What's wrong with export?  That gets you the comment block w/ hashes and the full git diff.